# Construct: (un)dumping bytes to hex

Tags: python, parsing, formatting, serialization

This code is part of the [Construct](https://github.com/construct/construct) library. Docstrings explain what the code is supposed to do.

```
from construct.lib.py3compat import byte2int, int2byte, bytes2str, iteratebytes, iterateints


# Map an integer in the inclusive range 0-255 to its string byte representation
_printable = dict((i, ".") for i in range(256))
_printable.update((i, bytes2str(int2byte(i))) for i in range(32, 128))


def hexdump(data, linesize):
    r"""
    Turns bytes into a unicode string of the format:

    >>>print(hexdump(b'0' * 100, 16))
    0000   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
    0010   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
    0020   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
    0030   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
    0040   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
    0050   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
    0060   30 30 30 30                                       0000             
    """
    prettylines = []
    fmt = "%%04X   %%-%ds   %%s" % (3 * linesize - 1,)
    fmtlinesize = 7 + 3*linesize + 3 + linesize
    for i in range(0, len(data), linesize):
        line = data[i:i+linesize]
        hextext = " ".join('%02x' % b for b in iterateints(line))
        rawtext = "".join(_printable[b] for b in iterateints(line))
        prettylines.append(fmt % (i, str(hextext), str(rawtext)))
    if prettylines:
        prettylines[-1] = prettylines[-1].ljust(fmtlinesize)
    prettylines.append("")
    return "\n".join(prettylines)


def hexundump(data, linesize):
    r"""
    Reverse of ``hexdump()``.
    """
    raw = []
    fmtlinesize = 7 + 3*linesize + 3 + linesize
    for line in data.split("\n"):
        bytes = [int2byte(int(s,16)) for s in line[7:7+3*linesize].split()]
        raw.extend(bytes)
    return b"".join(raw)
```

some of the code refers to: https://github.com/construct/construct/blob/master/construct/lib/py3compat.py

Comment: Could you write a summary of what this code is meant to do

Comment: @Jamal Considering your meta answer http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1938/are-code-only-questions-off-topic/1939#1939 I am surprised that you closed it.

Comment: Both answers there state that they aren't off-topic, but the other answer (that you've linked to) is consistent with what I've done here.

Comment: @Jamal The title and the docstring describe the code clearly enough to me. I've reopened the question.

Comment: @ArekBulski: The docstring looks fine to me, but I think many users here like to have an introduction explaining what the code does and what you would like to get out of the review. You could say, "please read the docstring" or words to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

1. The construct library implements a Python 2/3 compatibility layer. Would it make sense to use a third-party library here like [`six`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six)? Even if you have good reasons for using your own compatibility library, it might make sense to use the same interface names as `six`, for example [`iterbytes`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.iterbytes) instead of your `iterateints`. This would make it easier to collaborate with Python programmers who are used to the `six` interface.
2. The name `iteratebytes` is imported but not used.
3. There's no need to use `bytes2str` for compatibility here — `int2byte(i).decode('ascii')` works in both Python 2 and 3, since you know that `32 <= i < 128`.
4. In fact, I doubt that you need a `bytes2str` compatibility shim at all — `b.decode('latin1')` works for all byte strings in both Python 2 and 3.
5. The `_printable` data structure is a dictionary mapping numbers between 0 and 255 to their string representation. This would be slightly simpler if implemented as a list (because then there would be no need to store the keys):

   ```
   _printable = [int2byte(i).decode('ascii') if 32 <= i < 128 else '.'
                 for i in range(256)]
   ```
6. I think the `_printable` name could be improved — perhaps `_raw_repr` to parallel `rawtext`?
7. If it makes sense to cache the raw representation of bytes (as you do in the `_printable` data structure, then it also makes sense to cache the hexadecimal representation:

   ```
   _hex_repr = [format(i, '02X') for i in range(256)]
   ```
8. There does not seem to be any reason to make the docstring an `r`-string.
9. "Unicode" has a capital "U".
10. The doctest in the docstring does not pass.

    ```
    $ python -mdoctest cr143734.py
    **********************************************************************
    File "cr143734.py", line 11, in cr143734.hexdump
    Failed example:
        print(hexdump(b'0' * 100, 16))
    Expected:
        0000   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
        0010   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
        0020   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
        0030   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
        0040   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
        0050   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
        0060   30 30 30 30                                       0000             
    Got:
        0000   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
        0010   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
        0020   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
        0030   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
        0040   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
        0050   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
        0060   30 30 30 30                                       0000             
        <BLANKLINE>
    **********************************************************************
    1 items had failures:
       1 of   1 in cr143734.hexdump
    ***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
    ```
11. The computation of `fmtlinesize` is off by one. It uses `3*linesize` but the previous line has `3 * linesize - 1`.
12. Because of this off-by-one error, the last but one line of the output has an unnecessary extra space.
13. If there are more than 65535 bytes in `data`, then the formatting goes wrong:

    ```
    FFF0   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
    10000   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
    ```

    Since the `hexdump` function is given a byte string (and not, say, an iterable or a file object) it is easy to work out the necessary number of digits in the address.
14. The first argument to `hexundump` should have a different name — this is not the data, it's the dump of the data.
15. It seems inelegant for `hexundump` to take a `linesize` argument when this can be deduced from the dump.

Comment: For disclosure, I am the current maintainer of Construct and I did purge six from dependencies. Since the library already had both compatibility module and six, I just moved what I needed into pycompat and purged six. One less depencency. Import is copy pasted from `__init__`, skip that. Docstrings were not meant as doctests, I have a huge test suite for that.

Comment: What I took: `_printable` made into a list (indexing faster than of dict), `_hexprintable` also added, supporting 04X and 08X offsets on left side (larger wont be printed ever), `fmtlinesize` removed, and finally `linesize` could be computed but the way library is made, that value is always available.

Comment: @ArekBulski: The point of doctest is not just to use the docstrings as part of your test suite, but also to check that the examples are correct.